# non-standard types in C function prototype

Tags: c, prototype

I am trying to use a defined type ("config_flags", defined in the struct below) in a C function prototype but am getting an error ("expected declaration specifiers").  My question is - is this possible in C and if so, how to do so?  TIA.

```
struct grid_config_rec_type {
int  scalar_adv_op;
int  h_sca_adv_order;
int  v_sca_adv_order;
}config_flags;

void advect_scalar_      (float ,float ,float ,float ,float ,float ,float ,int , 
config_flags ,float ,float ,float ,float ,float ,
float ,float ,float ,float,
float ,float ,int ,int ,int ,int ,int ,int ,int ,
int ,int ,int ,int ,int ,int ,int ,int ,int ,int ,int );
```

Comment: What the hell is this monstrosity of a function? Also `config_flags` is not a type, it's an object. Perhaps you forgot to `typedef`?

Comment: The way you have defined it `config_flags` is not a type name, but a struct variable of type `struct grid_config_rec_type`.

Comment: You have defined a type named `struct grid_config_rec_type`, and a *variable* of that type named `config_flags`.  The latter identifier is not a valid type.  Did you perhaps forget to use `typedef`?

Comment: Following up on the "monstrosity" comment, if your function really needs that many parameters, I think you'd be better off defining a structure type to contain the parameters and passing a pointer to that. With so many consecutive arguments of the same type, the probability of passing the arguments incorrectly is pretty high.

Comment: With that many params, even if they are all defined in a struct, I suspect the function is trying to do far too much, and likely needs to be broken up so each of several functions perform a single piece of the work that may be happening in this one.

Comment: Thanks for all of your excellent comments/suggestions.  Being in java most of the time lately, my C has diminished somewhat so I forgot about typedef.  I have since added it before "struct" to create the new type config_flags.  Point taken also on the "monstrosity" comment.  It is definitely "ugly".  I'm converting from Fortran to C (weather model code) and they are passing _lots_ of variables.  Andy - yours is a good idea in regards to avoiding passing that many parameters.  Will definitely consider it.  thx.